# How to optimize a table containing 1 billion rows, fixed row format using myisam engine in mysql?

Tags: linux, unix, performance, mysql, database

I am having a table containing 1 billion rows, fixed row format and using myisam engine in mysql. I am thinking of shardding the table but that development takes time. Are there any temporary solutions for improving the performance?

Comment: How wide are the rows? Do you have sufficient indexes? Are you using fulltext fields? We need more info - preferably your DB schema.

Comment: How about the select/insert ratio?

Comment: PK on 3 out of 4 columns, all 4 columns ints..

Comment: Please run SHOW INDEXES FROM tblname; on this table and display its output in this question

Comment: Insufficient information for meainingful answer; we need to know *what is the problem*. Is it concurrency? Slow queries with a specific form? there are a huge number of possible answers, most of which will be wrong without more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at mysql partitioning. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html
it allows you to distribute portions of individual tables across a file system transparent to your queries

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment if  "insert/select ratio = 100:1" is the case, then i don see any reason to have indexes (apart from primary key index if any) on the table. It will further slow down your inserts.

Also, if you can queue inserts to this table then you can try creating a in-memory table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) and direct all the inserts to the table which will be faster and then do a bulk insert/periodic flush in to ur myisam engine based table.

Also you can partition the table on a specific column out of those 4 you have(if there is any good candidate) or go for hash based partition (if you don find any).  I am not sure why you are saying sharding is going to take dev time. you can partition an existing non partitioned table too. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,264106,264110

Comment: In my experience indexes are usually always worthwhile. I often build an index on a temporary table used for only a single select statement, as it can be faster to index, select and drop, than to select and drop.